# Text-Overflow Ellipsis not working for multi-lines in Firefox and IE browsers

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement **Ellipsis** after few lines. I have implemented this

https://jsfiddle.net/eqo74h3p/1/

It is working in Chrome but not in Firefox, IE.

**css**

```
 line-height: 1.7;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: `-webkit-` only works in WebKit browsers like Chrome & Safari.

Comment: Yeah, but what about firefox,IE. Any alternative?

Comment: Not that I know of. Also note that `display: -webkit-box` is old and you should use `display: flex;`.

Answer (score 2):

Because Firefox doesn’t support `webkit-line-clamp` (then doesn't show ellipsis), we can do some tricks with `::after` selector (without `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and `-webkit-line-clamp: 4;`), something like this:

## For Firefox (also for IE or other browser):

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 85px;
  max-height:72px; 
  line-height: 21px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  word-break: break-all;
}

p::after {
  letter-spacing: .10em;
  content:"...";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:-10px;
  padding:0 11px 4px 45px;
}
```

```html
<p>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
```

> ***It is showing dots even if it is a single line***

We can do some Jquery tricks to add `ellipsis` only if needed. *(Just an Idea)*

See this simple DEMO to explain my idea, I hope it helps.

```js
var el = $('.P_One');
var bo = $('.One');
var el2 = $('.P_Two');
var bo2 = $('.Two');

if (el.get(0).scrollHeight > bo.height()) {
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.P_One::after','content:"..."; letter-spacing: .10em; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:-10px; padding:0 11px 4px 45px;');
}

if (el2.get(0).scrollHeight > bo2.height()) {
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.P_Two::after','content:"..."; letter-spacing: .10em; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:-10px; padding:0 11px 4px 45px;');
}
```

```css
.One{
  width: 400px;
  height: 85px;
  max-height:72px; 
  margin-bottom:40px;
}

.P_One, .P_Two {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 85px;
  max-height:72px; 
  line-height: 21px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="One">
 <p class="P_One">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
</div>
<div class="Two">
 <p class="P_Two">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap;`

https://jsfiddle.net/eqo74h3p/2/

Answer (score 0):

Well there are some few reasons for why your CSS is not working, use my css setting below for the right way:

```
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: -webkit-box; // use this not the block
  height: 85px; // change this lower then the lines you have
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px; // use pixels nog 1.7
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4; // use this and put in more lines then 4.
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Hopefully this will work for you.